# How to create simple plugin in craft CMS4

Tags: plugins, craftcms

I am new to this craft cms and plugin creation.
I did research lot to build a really very simple plugin in my local machine and try to install in craft cms 4 but no luck.

I have followed this document to build it https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/plugin-guide.html#composer-json.

Does anyone know any detail document to create plugin and install it in craft?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There is a [Craft Generator utility](https://github.com/craftcms/generator/) that exist now for Craft 4 plugins. Craft 4 has a pretty decent migration utility from Craft 3 to Craft 4 that you can run if you've already developed a Craft 3 plugin. I updated one of my plugins without any issue in the Craft admin when updating a site from Craft 3 to Craft 4.

I've used  [craftquest.io](https://craftquest.io/articles/generate-craft-cms-plugin-and-module-code) a lot to learn about how to make a Craft 4 plugin and their videos and articles are really helpful in understanding how to extend Craft 4 out of the box.

[Craft Generator](https://github.com/craftcms/generator) is a CLI tool that you can run to setup your Craft 4 plugin. It's a little cumbersome but there is some documentation on the git page and utilizes composer.

[Here is a link](https://craftcms.com/blog/craft-generator) to the documentation on the main Craft CMS site for utilizing the cli tool Craft generator. Hopefully this helps point you in the right direction.